# How do I add a new numbered section in a multi-level list?

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

I have a document where sections are created using the `Heading 1`, `Heading 2`, `Heading 3`, etc styles. In a previous revision I was able to automatically number them, like so:

[image: heading numbered]

I cannot remove these numbers by selecting the "None" style under the multi-level list dropdown.

I want to insert a new `Heading 1` section in the middle of the document, which changes the numbering.

I can simply select the multi-level list again after adding this section, but it keeps the old numbers, eg:

[image: numbering doesnt update]

Ideally I would like to add new sections and update the numbering, or alternatively, remove the old numbering and add new numbering.

Comment: If you are changing the numbering so that following numbers will follow separate rules, you need two different lists, each with each level tied to a distinct paragraph style. Here are links to two pages that describe this process. One for the Windows versions(http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html), one for the Mac versions (http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/). This is not simple, but it is necessary, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add another Heading 1 paragraph and keep all of the automatic numbering working correctly, you have to add the new Heading 1 paragraph at the end of the previous Heading 1 paragraph's range span. The range span of each heading goes until a new Heading of the same level or higher is encountered, or the end of the document. Thus a Heading 1 has a range span that encompasses all subordinate Heading 2, 3, etc, and it runs until the start of the next Heading 1 or end of the document, whichever comes first.

Here's an example of where you would insert a new Heading 1 so that all numbering adjusts accordingly. The place is marked by the red arrow.

[image]

This is the result. See how the numbering automatically changed.

[image]

If on the other hand, you insert as this following example shows, between a Heading 2 and Heading 3 range of the previous Heading 1 range, you get these results. Notice that Heading 3 has renumbered to its new master Heading 1, but the subordinate numbering is incorrect.

[image]

To correct this numbering problem you have to either insert a new Heading 2 or change the Heading 3 paragraph to a Heading 2 paragraph.

[image]